# Start Android navigation for result

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation

I am creating an app where I need to start the navigation app and then use the result (most importantly the driven distance). I am starting the navigation activity with startActivityForResult and using the scheme "google.navigation". Like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(
    Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
    Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=Somewhere"));
startActivityForResult(i,1);
```

This works great, I get a callback when the activity is done, but the data portion of the activity is empty.

Is there a way to do this?

Is there a navigation history where I can browse the latest trip for data?

Best Regards
Jakob Simon-Gaarde

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about callbacks from Google Navigation. But if you are only interested in getting the driven distance, you could keep listening to the location updates in the background and calculate the distance yourself. The following function uses **`android.location.Location`** to calculate distance between two LatLang coordinates:

```
public double getGeodesicDistance(LatLng from, LatLng to){
    Location _fromLoc = new Location("From location");
    _fromLoc.setLatitude(from.latitude);
    _fromLoc.setLongitude(from.longitude);

    Location _toLoc = new Location("To location");
    _toLoc.setLatitude(to.latitude);
    _toLoc.setLongitude(to.longitude);

    return Math.round(_fromLoc.distanceTo(_toLoc)); // distance in metres
}
```

But if you decide to take this approach, you should detect the sudden jumps in GPS data and handle them accordingly.

Comment: This is the most result-oriented answer. I will investigate further!

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to do this?

No, there is no way for you to force an activity to give you a result. The determination of whether an activity supports a result lies in the authors of the activity, not the caller of the activity.

> Is there a navigation history where I can browse the latest trip for data?

There is no documented and supported API for the Google Navigation Android app (which includes the `google.navigation` scheme).

Comment: I know I can't force an answer out of an activity. I miss documentation from google about there built-in scheme activities.

Answer (score 2):

You could get the location right before you start the navigation, and get it again once the navigation is closed, and calculate the difference.

Comment: This doesn't give me the actual driven mileage, but an estimate based on distance-calculation.